# Filename and editing permissions are gone from Finder Tags

Tags: finder, finder-tag

I just added two pdf files in a Tag group and I the filename is blank even though in a normal finder windows I can see it.

An other problem is that if I select the file and I press enter to edit the name, nothing happens.

I tried to add extra files on the group and it seams to work fine with everything else.

I also tried to change the Tag group of the file, but same problem.

I checked the permissions and are totally fine. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you dod some screenshots

Comment: Yes! I just did

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the `mds` service and the problem was fixed. I also re-indexed my hard drive.